# Fix Page Layout When Resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for a school project and well have run into a problem. Whenever I resize my screen, all the things move and warp in size, the list, especially. Is there a way where I can wrap all the items so that when the screen resizes (when I drag it horizontally/vertically to make it smaller) everything stays in place and I just see less of what is on the screen and need to scroll to see the rest? I tried setting everything to em/px instead but that still left me with white space and a messed up list bar.

Here's the CSS

```
#title{
font-family:basic title font;
color:#ffffff;
position: absolute;
left:33%;
top:-2.3%;
font-size:1.6em;
z-index:1;}

#intro{
font-family:basic title font;
color:#636363;
position: absolute;
left:62%;
top:32%;
font-size:2.5em;
 z-index:1;
font-weight:900;}

#schedule{
font-family:basic title font;
color:#636363;
position: absolute;
left:35%;
top:28%;
font-size:3em;
z-index:1;
font-weight:900;
}
#skl {
z-index:100;
position:absolute;
width:34%;
left:7%;
top:37%;
z-index:1;}
#box {
 width:28%;
height:60%;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
position:absolute;
top:48%;
left:54%;
}
#box2 {
width:28%;
height:60%;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
position:absolute;
top:48%;
left:19%;
}
#wordbox1 {
width:28%;
height:30%;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
position:absolute;
top:111%;
left:19%;
}
#wordbox2 {
width:28%;
height:30%;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
position:absolute;
top:111%;
left:54%;
}

#box3 {
width:26%;
height:6%;
background-color: white;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:20%;
}
#box4 {
width:26%;
height:6%;
background-color: white;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:55%;
}

#q1{
 width:28%;
 height:14%;
 background-color: #D6D6D6;
position:absolute;
top:144%;
left:19%;
}

#q2{
width:28%;
height:14%;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
position:absolute;
top:144%;
left:54%;
}
#text
{font-family:basic title font;
color:#636363;
    position: absolute;
left:38.5%;
top:1.2%;
font-size:4em;
z-index:1;}
#text2
{font-family:basic title font;
color:#636363;
position: absolute;
    left:55%;
top:1.2%;
font-size:4em;
z-index:1;}
#logo {
position:absolute;
top:5%;
    left:43%;
z-index:1;
width:12%;

}
#midbar {
width:100%;
height:6%;
background-color: #636363;
position:absolute;
top:22%;
}
#bar {
width:100%;
height:160%;
background-color: #F0F0F0;
position:absolute;
top:28%;
}


#midbar2 {
width:100%;
height:17%;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
position:absolute;
top:5%;
}

#midbar3 {
width:100%;
height:5%;
background-color: #636363;
position:absolute;
top:0%;
}

#divider {
width:100%;
height:1%;
background-color: #636363;
position:absolute;
top:88%;
}


body {
color: #fff;
font-family: 'open sans'; 
font-size: 1.1em;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:100;
display:inline;
}





#primary_nav_wrap
{
margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
float:left;
margin:0;
top:22%;
left:9%;
padding:0;
max-width:100%;
min-width:50%;
max-height:500px;
min-height:21%;
text-align:center;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:700;
font-size:12px;
line-height:32px;
padding:0 15px;
font-family: 'open sans'; 
font-weight:100;
font-size: 0.9em;
color: #ffffff;
text-align:center;
padding-top:0.5em;
padding-bottom:0.5em;
padding-right:4em;
padding-left:4em;


}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul    
{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0%;
text-align:left;
background-color:#636363;

z-index:100;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
float:none;
    width:187px;
padding-left:1em;
padding-right:1em;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
line-height:120%;
padding:10px 15px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
top:0;
left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
display:block
}


.hvr-fade {
  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
}
.hvr-fade:hover, .hvr-fade:focus, .hvr-fade:active {
 box-shadow:         inset 0 2px 10px -5px #000000;
  background-color: #2098d1;
  color: white;

z-index:1
}


    #bottomtext {
position:absolute;
bottom:-83%;
left:43%;
font-family:"myriad pro";
font-weight:300;
color:black;
font-size:0.8em;
z-index:10000;}
#bottomtext2 {
position:absolute;
bottom:-89%;
left:44%;
font-family:"myriad pro";
font-weight:200;
color:black;
font-size:0.6em;
z-index:1000000}
#bottom {
width:100%;
height:15%;
background-color: white;
position:absolute;
bottom:-88%;
z-index:1000;
}


a    { text-decoration: none; }
p    { text-align: center; }
sup  { font-size: 36px; font-weight: 100; line-height: 55px; }

.button
{
      text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0C5;

  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;

  margin: 4em auto;

  position: absolute; 
  top:150%; right:0; bottom:0; left:-34%;

  padding: 10px 0;
      padding-bottom:20px;
  width: 28%;
  height:2%;

  background: #2098d1;
      border: 1px solid #2098d1;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;

  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button:hover, .button:active 
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2098d1;
  border-color: #2098d1;
  background: #FFF;
}

.button span 
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0;

  transition: padding-right 0.5s;
}

.button span:after 
{
  content: ' ';  
  position: absolute;
      top: 0;
  right: -18px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px solid #2098d1;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;

  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.button:hover span, .button:active span 
{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.button:hover span:after, .button:active span:after 
{
  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
      opacity: 1;
  border-color: #2098d1;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}





a        { text-decoration: none; }
p    { text-align: center; }
sup  { font-size: 36px; font-weight: 100; line-height: 55px; }

.move
{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0C5;

  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;

  margin: 4em auto;

  position: absolute; 
  top:150%; right:0; bottom:0; left:36%;

  padding: 10px 0;
  padding-bottom:20px;
      width: 28%;
  height:2%;

  background: #2098d1;
  border: 1px solid #2098d1;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;

  transition: all 0.5s;
}    

.move:hover, .move:active 
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2098d1;
  border-color: #2098d1;
  background: #FFF;
}

.move span 
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0;

  transition: padding-right 0.5s;
}

.move span:after 
{
  content: ' ';  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -18px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px solid #2098d1;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;

  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.move:hover span, .move:active span 
{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.move:hover span:after, .move:active span:after 
{
  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: #2098d1;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

AND HERE'S THE HTML!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <meta charset='UTF-8'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sc.css"/>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,      maximum-scale=1">
     <meta name="robots" content="all,index,follow" />

     <title>KAS</title>
     <meta name="description" content="Create a sticky navigation bar that remains fixed to the top after scroll" />


 </head>
 <div id="wrapper"> 
 <body>
 <p id="title">SOUTHERN TAIWAN MODEL UNITED NATIONS</p>
 <p id="intro"></p>
 <p id="schedule">SECURITY COUNCIL</p>
 <p id="text">20 </p>
 <p id="text2">15 </p>

 <p id="bottomtext">Kfiller Afiller Sfiller <br>
 www.filler.com </p>
 <p id="bottomtext2">(c) 2015 by FIller Filler Filler</p>
 <div id="bottom"></div>

 <img id="logo" src="images/logo2.png">
 <div id="topbar"></div>
 <div id="midbar"></div>
 <div id="midbar2"></div>
 <div id="midbar3"></div>
 <div id="bar"></div>
 <div id="bar2"></div>
 <div id="box"></div>
 <div id="box2"></div>
 <div id="box3"></div>
 <div id="box4"></div>
 <div id="q1"></div>
 <div id="q2"></div>
 <div id="wordbox1"></div>
 <div id="wordbox2"></div>
 </div>


 <a href="#" class="button">
   <span>Download Chair Report</span>
 </a>

 <a href="#" class="move">
   <span>Download Chair Report</span>
 </a>


 <div id="whitebox"></div>
 <!--<div id="divider"></div>--!>

 <img id="skl" src="">


 <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
 <ul>
   <li class="hvr-fade" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-fade" ><a href="#">INTRODUCTION</a></li>

   <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">COMMITTEES</a>
     <ul >
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">Security Council</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">CDIS</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">ECOSOC</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">HRC</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">General Assembly 1</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">General Assembly 2</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">General Assembly 3</a></li>

     </ul>

   <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">MORE</a></li>

 </ul>
 </nav>
```

It's my first website. Thanks for any and all input! :D

Comment: Responsive web design framework required, try Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: You should use a responsive framework. you should read [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/responsive-design-frameworks-just-because-you-can-should-you/). I used both Bootstrap and Foundation and I considered them pretty useful.

Comment: media queries in css allow you to specify properties on certain elements with a condition of screen size / resolution. If you want something more cutting edge you might consider a layout completely in flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

First the `<div id="wrapper">` should come inside body tag

To solve your problem try setting min-width to body in CSS.

eg.

```
body{
min-width:720px;//or whatever value
}
```

if the screen width is less than 720px a horizontal scroll will appear

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, do I need to change anything else first?

Answer (score 0):

So the biggest problem with your CSS is that you've assigned practically everything a `position:absolute;` While you might think this is a good idea to control the elements on the page, it actually removes them from the natural flow of the page.  I'm not going to explain more about what this is actually doing ([but here's a link to help](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)).  I'm just going to give you some suggestions on what to do next.

The majority of your site is composed of elements that are block level; things that naturally span the width of the container (in your case the `body` element).  Typically what I do to create a responsive page is set two properties for the things directly inside the body as the following:

```
.childrenOfTheBody{
    max-width:720px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

What this will do is if the page goes beyond 760px wide, then that element of the page will automatically center itself on the page and become 760px wide.  Generally, you'd do this on a container element and then put child elements inside of that so you don't need to add these properties to everything.  This is how you would center block elements (`div`, `h1`, `p`).  Centering inline elements is easy; just use `text-align:center;` (`span`, `img`, `a`).  Speaking of, why does your `body` have `display:inline;`?

Comment: Since I don't have a container element, should I just make it a class and add it to all my elements on HTML?

Comment: Won't this still cause all my elements to move when the page is resized? I want them all to stay put and have a scroll bar instead.

Comment: You want a horizontal scrollbar?